# How to create and bind an empty multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I want to create a empty multidimensional array and then bind it to an existing array.

If my array was not empty, I can bind it with the `abind` package:

```
library(abind)
c=matrix(0,2,3)
test=array(0,c(2,3,1))
test2=abind(test,c,along=3)
test2 #exactly what I expected
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
```

Now I want to do the same thing except instead of two full arrays, I want one of them to be empty. Here is what would happen if I had characters:

```
test3=character() #this is empty
test3=c(test3,'hi') #I bind the word hi to it
test3
[1] "hi"
```

This does not exactly work if I try to use arrays:

```
empty=array()
abind(empty,test,along=3)
Error in abind(empty, test, along = 3) : 
'X1' does not fit: should have `length(dim())'=3 or 2
```

So I am assuming that `array()` is not how you create an empty multidimensional array.

Note the differences between the two commands:

```
empty=array()
> empty
[1] NA
test3=character()
> test3
character(0)
```

Comment: I don't think `array`s can be empty in the same way a `vector` can be. E.g. `array(numeric(0),dim=c(3,3,3))` and `array(numeric(0),dim=c(3,3,3))` Also consider the results of `vector("character",0)` and `vector("character",1)`

Comment: @thelatemail I think so too, but I was hoping someone here would prove me wrong

Comment: You, need to set at least one `dimension length = 0`... for vector is easy since it's just one dimension (and doing `numeric()` you are saying that dimension one length is zero), but for multi-dimensional structures (matrices or arrays) you need to set at least one `dimension length = 0`. Check my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define an empty array for example in this way:

```
empty <- array(numeric(),c(2,3,0))
```

Note that you need ***to set at least one dimension to zero***, otherwise the array will contain something by definition. Think for example to a matrix, if you define both dimensions greater than zero, you automatically instantiate a rectangular structure and it cannot be empty, at most it can be filled by NAs.

That being said, `abind` works like `rbind/cbind` but in a generalized way.
So, as `rbind/cbind` add a 1-dimensional structure to a 2-dimensional one, using `abind` with a 3-dimensional array, you need to add a 2-dimensional structure to the original array, since you want to *append a new structure to a chosen dimension*.

Here's an example of `abind` usage starting from a 3-dimensional empty array:

Create an empty array 2 x 3 x 0 :

```
a <- array(numeric(),c(2,3,0)) 

> a
<2 x 3 x 0 array of double>
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]
[2,]
```

Append a matrix (or a 2-dim array if you prefer) to the 3rd dimension of the array obtaining a new array 2 x 3 x 1 :

```
a <- abind(a, matrix(5,nrow=2,ncol=3), along=3)

> a
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    5    5
[2,]    5    5    5
```

Append a matrix again (or a 2-dim array if you prefer) to the 3rd dimension  of the previous array obtaining a new array 2 x 3 x 2 :

```
a <- abind(a, matrix(7,nrow=2,ncol=3), along=3)

> a
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    5    5
[2,]    5    5    5

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    7    7
[2,]    7    7    7
```

and so and so forth...